# jquery: code after if/else statement inside .scroll function does not work.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function, and inside of it is all of the events for my website that need to be fired if the user scrolls. However, the last line of code does not work, also `console.log();` does not fire if it is placed after the if/else statement either.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// make homepage CTA and rainbow bar disappear once top of below mountain hits those divs
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if($('.below-the-mountain').offset().top < $('.the-observable-universe').offset().top + 100){
    $('.cta').css('display', 'none');
    $('.rainbow').css('display', 'none');
}else{
    $('.cta').css('display', 'block');
    $('.rainbow').css('display', 'inline-block');
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// this is the code that does not fire, and it's because of the if/else statement above it
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$('.cat-title').css('top', $('.before-shop-loop').offset().top + $('.cat-title').height() / 2 - $('.header').height()); 
});
```

Does a javascript function stop running once an `if/else` statement evaluates true sort of like how `return` does?

This following code works.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// make title text all parralaxy so it stays in view as long as possible
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$('.cat-title').css('top', $('.before-shop-loop').offset().top + $('.cat-title').height() / 2 - $('.header').height());

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// make homepage CTA and rainbow bar disappear once top of below mountain hits those divs
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if($('.below-the-mountain').offset().top < $('.the-observable-universe').offset().top + 100){
    $('.cta').css('display', 'none');
    $('.rainbow').css('display', 'none');
}else{
    $('.cta').css('display', 'block');
    $('.rainbow').css('display', 'inline-block');
}

});
```

Why, what's the main difference/importance of order in this situation?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Comment: I cannot. the if/else and the other line are related to two seperate pages on the site. So a fiddlee would not replicate the issue I think

Answer (score 0):

I think You have an script error in if/else condition, put the line `window.onerror = function(e){alert(e)}` outside of scroll function, if any errors, it will alert you.

Comment: The logic in the if/else statement is correct. However, it does relate to a seperate page so it throws an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` in the console. Will an uncaught typerror cause a function to exit prematurely?

Comment: also, the console is a lot more efficient than using alerts to debug, just an fyi :)

Comment: Yes, this is the cause to break the script,  as per error `Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`, you should take into variable i.e `var a = $('.below-the-mountain').offset()` then follow the condition as `if(a && a.top > something)`